# multiselect dropdown with optgroup using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dropdown, multi-select

How to solved error array to string in multiselect dropdown with optgroup using codeigniter?

function in model :

```
function getZonaTree2() {
$types = $this->getZonaType();
$tree = array(''=>'-- Region --');
$this->getListTreeParent($listZona, 0, 0);
foreach($listZona as $r) {
    if($r->LEVEL==1) {
        $tree[$r->ZONA_NAME] = array();
        $zona_parent_1 = $r->ZONA_NAME;
    }
    if($r->LEVEL==2) {
        $tree[$zona_parent_1][$r->ZONA_NAME] = array();
        $zona_parent_2 = $r->ZONA_NAME;
    }
    if($r->LEVEL==3) {
        $tree[$zona_parent_1][$zona_parent_2][$r->ZONA_ID] = $r->ZONA_NAME." (".$r->ZONA_CAPITAL.") - ".$types[$r->TYPE];
    }
}
return $tree;
```

}

view :

```
<?php echo form_multiselect('zona_id', $this->Zona_model->getZonaTree2(), array(), "size=8 id='zona_id'"); ?>
```

[image: I want to make multilevel dropdown, to level 1 and 2 already managed to perform, but to level 3 get the error array to string.Here's how it looks]

Comment: edit your question to reflect problem your facing or error. what is your desired result?

Comment: I want to make multilevel dropdown, to level 1 and 2 already managed to perform, but to level 3 get the error array to string.Here's how it looks already I attach